# Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI:

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, onesignal

> Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl842607806.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #108): com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'

Answer (score 1):

If you’re targeting Android 12, you need to set

> android:exported

on each activity, service, and receiver on your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Follow the [link](https://cafonsomota.medium.com/android-12-dont-forget-to-set-android-exported-on-your-activities-services-and-receivers-3bee33f37beb) for more details.

Comment: Kindly check out my Manifest

Comment: add in <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"    android:exported="true"   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

Answer (score 0):

If possible, include '**android:exported="true"**' for any activity or service that uses an intent filter.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".myActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Kindly check out my Manifest

Comment: @MianLabib read this carefully  " If possible, include 'android:exported="true"' for any activity or service that uses an intent filter. "  not for all

Answer (score 0):

Add  `android:exported="true"`  in your  `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` at

```
 <manifest ...  <application...  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
```

[image]